# UITapGestureRecognizer conflict with didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2

well before i ask this i try the other solutions and it didn't work

this is my code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "didTouchBoard:")
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = true
}
```

when i click anywhere it will hide the keyboard if exist , but if i click on tableviewcell or collectionviewcell , it won't click

i try this tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView , but not work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want table view to receive touch, then change tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView

```
tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```

Comment: i was using true , not false ,,

Comment: @AhmedSafadi Happens) Can you please upvote my answer? I am new here and trying to build reputation.

Comment: sure , it help me so much ^^"

Answer (score 3):

You have to add the UITextFeildDelegate methods to enable and disable tap gesture in the view

1. declare tapGesture outside the view did load method

`let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "didTouchBoard:")`

2. implement the following methods

   ```
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
   self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.tapGesture) }
   ```

   func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
           self.view.removeGestureRecognizer(self.tapGesture)
       }

i think that might work for you

Comment: you don't have to add and remove the recognizer. You can simply switch `.enabled = true` and `.enabled = false`.